# How do you handle a 500 error from an embedded document in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, error-handling, jsx

I'm working on a React project which includes an embedded pdf object in the JSX. Given this is not a regular HTTP request in the traditional sense, I need help handling the case of an error. In my case I'm receiving a 500. Here is the JSX:

```
 return (
      <div className="policyViewDocumentContainer">
        <AccountFlowHeader guid={guid} history={history} handleSignOut={this.handleSignOut} />
        <p className="Header">
          Card
        </p>
        <hr />
        <div className="policyViewDocumentInnerContainer">
          <iframe
            title="Document"
            data={`https://agency.${env}api.up.com/agency/policyNumber/${contractNum}`}
            type="application/pdf"
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 130px',
            }}
          >
            <embed
              src={`https://agency.${env}api.up.com/agency/policyNumber/${contractNum}`}
              type="application/pdf"
            />
          </iframe>
          <div />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

I'm currently receiving the following error and I'm not sure how to handle it. I'd like to display either a modal or some other jsx in the event of a 500.

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Sat Nov 30 04:26:06 UTC 2019</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>Empty PDF Document</div></body></html>
```

Comment: look up your url for server access

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on this?

Comment: GeneralyIt happens when url is incorrect or passing parameter is incurrect or server is not running